# Django Choice Field similar as in Admin (Permissions)

Tags: django, django-templates

Unfortunately we have some really long drop down lists for our users to choose from and the way the django admin implemented their permissions ui really looks like a good solution for this, but for the life of me I can't find any examples how to implement something similar?

Does anyone has any tipps? (I currently use "Select2MultipleWidget" to at least make it somewhat manageable)

[image]

Template:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>

 
 {{ form.media }}

    <div style="position: relative">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.date|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.priceplan|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.account|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

urls.py:

```
#Multiple Select Widget without this non-admins won't have this rendered correctly
re_path(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog')
```

forms.py:

```
priceplan = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=WrmAutPricePlan.objects.order_by(), required=False,
                                           widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Price Plan", is_stacked=False))
account = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=WrmAutAccount.objects.all(), required=False,
                                         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Account", is_stacked=False))

class Media:
            css = {'all':('/admin/css/widgets.css', 'admin/css/overrides.css'),}
            js = ('/admin/jquery.js','/admin/jsi18n/')
```

Comment: why not look at django's source code and use the same widget? `django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple`

Comment: Thanks it works now after a lot of formatting and getting it to load for non admin users was a bit of a hassle, I will edit above :)